How to check if specified file path exists using pyspark
I have a 2 dictionaries as below
data_path = {
                "person": "/data/raw/person/*",
                "location": "/data/raw/location/*",
                "person_int": "/data/test/person_int/",
                "location_int": "/data/test/location_int/*"
            }

interim_tables = {
                    "person_int": ['ID', 'NAME', 'DATE'],
                    "location_int": ['ID', 'LOCATION', 'DATE'],
                    "person": ['ID', 'NAME', 'DATE']
                 }

I need to check if the interim table exists in the path.
If it exists, I need to load the incremental(delta) data.
If it does not exist, I need to load the historical data from the 'person' and 'location' tables.
This is my code below:
check_results={}
for table, cols in interim_tables.items():
    if table in data_path:
        path=data_path[table]
        
        if os.path.exists(path):
            check_results[table] = "path exists"
            # << logic to load incremental(delta) data >>
        else:
            check_results[table] = "path not exists"
            # << logic to load historical data >>

for table, status in check_results.items():
    print(f"{table}---{status})

At present, I have only person and location path available. person_int and location_int does not exist.
But I'm getting the output as:
person_int---path not exists
location_int---path not exists
person---path not exists

What is the correct approach for this?

I tried using glob.glob(path).. This did not help either

Why do you have * in the paths?

I have multiple date-wise folders under person, location. I need to access all the data under those folders

have you tried PathLib ?

what's it got to do with pyspark or spark?

The first issue you are facing is that the os.path.exists() does not interpret wildcards like * in filepath. Instead you should be using glob.glob() but as you mentioned in the comments it didn't work for you which gets us to your second issue.
The second issue is caused by the leading / in the file paths in data_path. This leading slash typically signifies the root directory in Unix-like systems, which caused the paths to mismatch with the actual structure. Removing the / from the start of the paths fixed the issue.
Your modified solution can look like this:
import glob

data_path = { 
    "person": "data/raw/person/*",
    "location": "data/raw/location/*",
    "person_int": "data/test/person_int/",
    "location_int": "data/test/location_int/*"
}

interim_tables = {
    "person": ['ID', 'NAME', 'DATE'],
    "person_int": ['ID', 'NAME', 'DATE'],
    "location_int": ['ID', 'LOCATION', 'DATE'],
}

check_results = {}

for table, cols in interim_tables.items():
    if table in data_path:
        path = data_path[table]
        
        # Use glob to handle wildcard paths
        matching_files = glob.glob(path)
        
        if matching_files:  # Check if any file exists for the given pattern
            check_results[table] = "path exists"
            # Logic to load incremental (delta) data
        else:
            check_results[table] = "path not exists"
            # Logic to load historical data
            
for table, status in check_results.items():
    print(f"{table}---{status}")

I tested this by creating a dummy path for person and got the following result which is correct:
person---path exists 
person_int---path not exists 
location_int---path not exists

